# How to fetch data from a query by extracting month from the created date field

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table and I want to extract data on the basis of the month value of the created date field. How can that be obtained?
Here is the query:

```
select *
from (table name a)
where select extract (month from a.createddate )from table name a
```

Table contains a field with timestamp type.

Comment: try `select * from a where extract (month from a.createddate ) = <your desired month goes here>` (assuming `a` is the phisical name of your  table)

Comment: Create a date variable with a value of the first day of the year and month of the createeddate field for the record in question.  Then look for record that are greater than on equal to that date and less than that date plus one month.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to apply a filter on the month of a `timestamp` column:

```
select *
from yourTable
where extract (month from yourField) = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

"On the basis of" is not specific enough. What does your actual condition look like? If your table is very large, and you do a lot of selecting "on the basis of" the month value of the created date column, you would do much better with an index on that column, and a condition that does NOT apply a function to created_date.

For example, suppose you want all the rows with a created_date in June 2015. The best way to do that is to have conditions

```
...where created_date >= date '2015-06-01' and created_date < date '2015-07-01'
```

or similar. It is OK to apply date functions to the right-hand side (if instead of June 2015 you had a bind variable, then the second comparison could be to `add_months(that_date, 1)`) since that would not prevent the use of an index on your `created_date` column; but any function applied to the column itself WILL prevent the use of an index and result in possibly much worse performance.

So, instead of starting with your current solution, you may get more useful help if you would state the original problem you were trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
  FROM dual
 WHERE TRUNC (systimestamp, 'MM') = TO_DATE ('20160901', 'YYYYMMDD');
```

You can run this as-is to test it out.

Change 'dual' to your table name, change 'systimestamp' to your column name.

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to use datepart.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE DATEPART(mm,CreatedDate) = x
```

Comment: That is not Oracle syntax